# Bootstrap, SCSS and PHP

Tags: php, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Lately, I've discovered **Bootstrap**, and I can't begin to explain how excited I was.
The thing is that, to override Bootstrap, one needs to use **SCSS** to be efficient (There's also a Less version, but that is not my point)

So reading about SCSS, it seems one needs to be using Ruby and Compass. The thing is I'm a **PHP programmer**, and until I've fully mastered this language, I can't afford to scatter my efforts. So my question is the following :

- Can Bootstrap, SCSS and PHP be used all together efficiently? Knowing that when I work, I keep modifying my CSS while coding in PHP most of the time.
- If not, is it a viable option to code front-end first using Ruby and SCSS, then compile my SCSS files into CSS and switch to PHP? I don't know but it seems quite time-consuming to me.

If you're a PHP programmer and use Bootstrap at the same time, please share with me your experience. How do you work? What tools do you use, etc... I'm keen for any bit of information you might provide me with.

Thank you.

Comment: Most of the times I firstly build my layout in `HTML+CSS`. Then I completely build the back-end with `PHP` without touching my markup.

Comment: [See answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218712/any-good-sass-parser-for-php)

Comment: You don't actually need to use Ruby (As in write code in Ruby) to use SASS or SCSS. You just need it to compile SASS or SCSS into css. Applications such as Compass or Codekit are tools to compile those things. Once it's compiled you can use the compiled css the way you ussualy do.

Comment: @TimothyOnggowasito Compass is just a wrapper around Sass, it requires Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use SCSS to be efficient. To me, the most efficient solution is whatever works easiest *for me.* You can simply include the bootstrap.css file in your stylesheets directory in your project to use as a foundation, and then create a seperate stylesheet for custom styles specific to your app.

Yes, SCSS is cool and there are some productivity gains to be made by using it, but its not required to use bootstrap.

To answer your question..

1. Yes, of course you can use Bootstrap, PHP, and CSS/CSS together efficiently. How you use them, is up to you. This can be as simple as including the bootstrap css in an external stylesheet in your project, or leveraging SCSS to be more expressive and organize your css rules. Whatever works for you.

Comment: Thank you, all three of you. You've given me food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

I agree 100% with [ply](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662955/ply) that whatever works best for you is the way to go.

Even though they do take a little work upfront, I'd encourage you not to write off [LESS](http://lesscss.org) or [SAAS](http://sass-lang.com) too early though.

Personally I'm in the LESS camp and I found I got a huge payback for the time invested getting up to speed with it. You end up with much cleaner CSS, you don't have to worry about all the vendor prefixes and the code nesting is awesome and really helps me keep things organised.

I use [CodeKit](https://incident57.com/codekit/) for compiling and there are heaps of other options. When I make a change to my less file, CodeKit automatically compiles it in the background and refreshes my browser view.

Cheers!